# Creating a Random Access File that stores multiple employee data using a loop

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

This is what the problem states:

Write a program called StoreEmployeeData that creates a Random Access File called 'EmployeeData.dat' that stores employee work data. Allow a user to enter the relevant data for three (3) employees using a loop and store it in the file. If the file already contains data, add the new data to what already exist.

The following is the code I've tried for this.

```
try {
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("EmployeeData.dat", "rw");
    long flength = f.length();
    f.seek(f.length());
    int hours = 0;
    String empid = "";
    double rate = 0;

   Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
     for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        hours=s.nextInt();
        empid=s.next();
        rate=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("");
    }

    f.close();
} // end try
```

The question also asks for:

Write a program called ProcessEmployeeData to do the following: 
Read the `EmployeeData.dat` file to determine the gross wage of each employee.   Create a text file called `EmployeeWage.txt` and store each employee’s ID and 
GROSS WAGE in the text file.

This must be done for any number of inputs.

I'm getting problems with the first part hence have not attempted the second part. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problems are you having? - You probably want to put spaces between each value you write, and you might want to write a newline after writing the three values so that each employee's data appears on its own line.  - Then there's that you don't have a loop and aren't doing anything with your Scanner object.

Comment: In your question you wrote: _Allow a user to enter the relevant data_. The code you posted does not address this. Do you know how to get user-entered data? Your code creates a `Scanner` but it is not used. Do you know how to use `Scanner` to get data entered by the user?

Comment: @Abra i've edited my code to suit, see above

Comment: Now you aren't writing anything to the file. - I would suggest using a String.format() statement to write your data in a single line.  Include a '\n' at the end of the format String you pass to String.format().

Comment: @Steve my lecturer specifically stated not to use that method..which is why i'm at a loss on what to do.

Comment: Is file "EmployeeData.dat" supposed to be a text file, i.e. should it contain text only? For example a GIF file contains an image. It does not contain text. Similarly a file can contain a serialized java object. Is file "EmployeeData.dat" meant to contain serialized java objects?

Comment: @Abra just a text file